# Taking a function stdout output to shell and print it tkinter

Tags: python, printing, tkinter, pafy

I am using the pafy module to download YouTube videos, but in one of the pafy functions, called `download` it prints to the screen the progress of the download, I would like to take that output and put it in my tkinter window.

Here is the pafy function:

```
video = pafy.new(url)
best_video = video.getbest(preftype="mp4")
write_prog("Started downloading "+video.title)
best_video.download()
```

The last function, `best_video.download()` is the one that prints to the screen.

Any ideas of how to do that?

Comment: Create a class whose `write` method outputs to the Tkinter window. Reassign `sys.stdout` to that object. You may need to do the video download in a separate thread, so Tkinter gets enough processing cycles to refresh its window between writes.

Comment: not sure why this got a downvote - it seems like a good qustion to me. I can think of two solutions : 1) redefine `sys.stdout` for the duration of the call so that it points to a `StringIO` (which looks like a file to any writing function/method), but can also be treated like a string, or 2) Run your download function as a separate process, and pipe the stdout of that process as appropriate.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: I would guess the downvote is because the question, while interesting, shows no research effort.

Comment: couldn't you create labels instead of 'printing'